# Modify normals after rotating a cube in WebGL

Tags: javascript, glsl, webgl

I'm trying to use normals for simple point lights on this simple scene, but I need the normals to modify correctly to the rotation of the cube.

Some notes for the code:

- The reason it's so large is because it uses multiple files, which provides more organization.
- The reasoning for the cube being rotated within the vertex shader but the cosine and sine operations being performed outside of it is due to performance improvements.
- Instead of changing a buffer for, say, 100 cubes and rotating each and every one of them, in order to rotate the cube, we just need to input one buffer. If you just want to rotate the model view projection, that's fine, but if you want to have two cubes (side by side) rotating in different directions or have a first-person shooter with different rotating objects, that's nearly impossible.

```js
// "shaders.js"
const vsSource = [
  `attribute vec4 aVertexPosition;`,
  `attribute vec3 aVertexNormal;`,
  `uniform mat4 uModelViewMatrix;`,
  `uniform mat4 uProjectionMatrix;`,
  `uniform mat4 uNormalMatrix;`,
  `uniform vec3 uTransform;`,
  `uniform vec2 uRotationX;`,
  `uniform vec2 uRotationY;`,
  `uniform vec2 uRotationZ;`,
  `varying highp vec3 vLighting;`,
  `void main(void) {`,
  ` vec4 p = aVertexPosition;`,
  ` float n0x = p.x * uRotationX.y + p.y * uRotationX.x;`,
  ` float n0y = p.y * uRotationX.y - p.x * uRotationX.x;`,
  ` float n0z = p.z;`,
  ` float n1x = n0x;`,
  ` float n1y = n0y * uRotationY.y + n0z * uRotationY.x;`,
  ` float n1z = n0z * uRotationY.y - n0y * uRotationY.x;`,
  ` float n2x = n1x * uRotationZ.y - n1z * uRotationZ.x;`,
  ` float n2y = n1y;`,
  ` float n2z = n1z * uRotationZ.y + n1x * uRotationZ.x;`,
  ` gl_Position = uProjectionMatrix * uModelViewMatrix * (vec4(vec3(n2x, n2y, n2z) + uTransform, p.w));`,
  ` highp vec3 ambientLight = vec3(0.3, 0.3, 0.3);`,
  ` highp vec3 directionalLightColor = vec3(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);`,
  ` highp vec3 directionalVector = normalize(vec3(0.85, 0.8, 0.75));`,
  ` highp vec4 transformedNormal = uNormalMatrix * vec4(aVertexNormal, 1.0);`,
  ` highp float directional = max(dot(transformedNormal.xyz, directionalVector), 0.0);`,
  ` vLighting = ambientLight + (directionalLightColor * directional);`,
  `}`
].join(`\n`);
const fsSource = [
  `varying highp vec3 vLighting;`,
  `void main(void) {`,
  ` gl_FragColor = vec4(vec3(1.0, 0.0, 0.0) * vLighting, 1.0);`,
  `}`
].join(`\n`);

const initShaders = (gl) => {
  const vertexShader = gl.createShader(gl.VERTEX_SHADER),
    fragmentShader = gl.createShader(gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);
  gl.shaderSource(vertexShader, vsSource);
  gl.shaderSource(fragmentShader, fsSource);
  gl.compileShader(vertexShader);
  if (!gl.getShaderParameter(vertexShader, gl.COMPILE_STATUS)) {
    alert(`An error occurred compiling the shaders: ${gl.getShaderInfoLog(vertexShader)}`);
    gl.deleteShader(vertexShader);
    return null;
  };
  gl.compileShader(fragmentShader);
  if (!gl.getShaderParameter(fragmentShader, gl.COMPILE_STATUS)) {
    alert(`An error occurred compiling the shaders: ${gl.getShaderInfoLog(fragmentShader)}`);
    gl.deleteShader(fragmentShader);
    return null;
  };
  return {
    'vertex': vertexShader,
    'fragment': fragmentShader
  };
};
// "object.js"
class Obj {
  #positions;
  #index;
  #normals;
  get positions() {
    return [...(this.#positions)];
  };
  get index() {
    return [...(this.#index)];
  };
  get normals() {
    return [...(this.#normals)];
  };
  constructor(positions, index, normals) {
    if (typeof positions == `object` && typeof index == `object` && typeof normals == `object`) {
      this.#positions = positions;
      this.#index = index;
      this.#normals = index;
    } else {
      console.error(`Need "object" type, got: "${typeof positions}", "${typeof index}"`)
    };
    return;
  };
};

class Object {
  static Cube = class Cube extends Obj {
    constructor() {
      super([-1.0, -1.0, 1.0,
        1.0, -1.0, 1.0,
        1.0, 1.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0, 1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 1.0, -1.0,
        1.0, 1.0, -1.0,
        1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 1.0, 1.0,
        1.0, 1.0, 1.0,
        1.0, 1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0,
        1.0, -1.0, -1.0,
        1.0, -1.0, 1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 1.0,
        1.0, -1.0, -1.0,
        1.0, 1.0, -1.0,
        1.0, 1.0, 1.0,
        1.0, -1.0, 1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0, -1.0
      ], [
        0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 3,
        4, 5, 6, 4, 6, 7,
        8, 9, 10, 8, 10, 11,
        12, 13, 14, 12, 14, 15,
        16, 17, 18, 16, 18, 19,
        20, 21, 22, 20, 22, 23
      ], [
        0.0, 0.0, 1.0,
        0.0, 0.0, 1.0,
        0.0, 0.0, 1.0,
        0.0, 0.0, 1.0,
        0.0, 0.0, -1.0,
        0.0, 0.0, -1.0,
        0.0, 0.0, -1.0,
        0.0, 0.0, -1.0,
        0.0, 1.0, 0.0,
        0.0, 1.0, 0.0,
        0.0, 1.0, 0.0,
        0.0, 1.0, 0.0,
        0.0, -1.0, 0.0,
        0.0, -1.0, 0.0,
        0.0, -1.0, 0.0,
        0.0, -1.0, 0.0,
        1.0, 0.0, 0.0,
        1.0, 0.0, 0.0,
        1.0, 0.0, 0.0,
        1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0
      ]);
    };
  };
};

const getBuffers = (gl, clas) => {
  if (typeof clas != `function`) {
    console.error(`Need "function" type, got: "${typeof clas}"`);
    return;
  };
  const classy = new clas();
  var positions = classy.positions,
    index = classy.index,
    normals = classy.normals;
  if (positions != undefined && positions != null && index != undefined && index != null && normals != undefined && normals != null) {
    const positionBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, positionBuffer);
    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(positions), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
    const normalBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, normalBuffer);
    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(normals), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
    const indexBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indexBuffer);
    gl.bufferData(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, new Uint16Array(index), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
    return {
      'position': positionBuffer,
      'index': indexBuffer,
      'normal': normalBuffer
    }
  } else {
    console.error(`Need any input type, got: "${typeof positions}", "${typeof index}", "${typeof normals}"`);
  };
  return;
};
// "draw.js"
var doDraw,
  draw,
  drawRad;
(() => {
  const DTR = Math.PI / 180.0,
    RTD = 180.0 / Math.PI;
  var draws = [];
  doDraw = (gl, aVertexPosition, aVertexNormal, uProjectionMatrix, uModelViewMatrix, uNormalMatrix, uTransform, uRotationX, uRotationY, uRotationZ, projectionMatrix, modelViewMatrix) => {
    draws.forEach((e) => {
      const normalMatrix = mat4.create();
      mat4.invert(normalMatrix, normalMatrix);
      mat4.transpose(normalMatrix, normalMatrix);
      gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, e[`buffs`][`position`]);
      gl.vertexAttribPointer(aVertexPosition, 3, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
      gl.enableVertexAttribArray(aVertexPosition);
      gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, e[`buffs`][`normal`]);
      gl.vertexAttribPointer(aVertexNormal, 3, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
      gl.enableVertexAttribArray(aVertexNormal);
      gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, e[`buffs`][`index`]);
      gl.uniformMatrix4fv(uProjectionMatrix, false, projectionMatrix);
      gl.uniformMatrix4fv(uModelViewMatrix, false, modelViewMatrix);
      gl.uniformMatrix4fv(uNormalMatrix, false, normalMatrix);
      gl.uniform3fv(uTransform, e[`transform`]);
      gl.uniform2fv(uRotationX, e[`rotateX`]);
      gl.uniform2fv(uRotationY, e[`rotateY`]);
      gl.uniform2fv(uRotationZ, e[`rotateZ`]);
      gl.drawElements(gl.TRIANGLES, e[`count`], gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0); // LINE_LOOP, TRIANGLES
      return;
    });
    draws = [];
    return;
  };
  draw = (buffs, vertexCount, x, y, z, rx, ry, rz) => {
    const rxr = rx * DTR,
      ryr = ry * DTR,
      rzr = rz * DTR;
    draws.push({
      'buffs': buffs,
      'transform': [
        x,
        y,
        z
      ],
      'rotateX': [
        Math.sin(rxr),
        Math.cos(rxr)
      ],
      'rotateY': [
        Math.sin(ryr),
        Math.cos(ryr)
      ],
      'rotateZ': [
        Math.sin(rzr),
        Math.cos(rzr)
      ],
      'rx': rxr,
      'ry': ryr,
      'rz': rzr,
      'count': vertexCount
    });
    return;
  };
  drawRad = (buffs, vertexCount, x, y, z, rx, ry, rz) => {
    draws.push({
      'buffs': buffs,
      'transform': [
        x,
        y,
        z
      ],
      'rotateX': [
        Math.sin(rx),
        Math.cos(rx)
      ],
      'rotateY': [
        Math.sin(ry),
        Math.cos(ry)
      ],
      'rotateZ': [
        Math.sin(rz),
        Math.cos(rz)
      ],
      'rx': rx,
      'ry': ry,
      'rz': rz,
      'count': vertexCount
    });
    return;
  };
  return;
})();
// "script.js"
(() => {
  const DTR = Math.PI / 180.0,
    RTD = 180.0 / Math.PI;
  var gl,
    ctx,
    canvasgl,
    canvasctx,
    width = 0,
    height = 0,
    cubeBuffs,
    shaderProgram,
    vertexShader,
    fragmentShader,
    aVertexPosition,
    aVertexNormal,
    uProjectionMatrix,
    uModelViewMatrix,
    uNormalMatrix,
    uTransform,
    uRotationX,
    uRotationY,
    uRotationZ,
    aProjectionMatrix,
    aModelViewMatrix,
    projectionMatrix,
    modelViewMatrix,
    cx = 0.0,
    cy = 0.0,
    cz = 0.0,
    crx = 0.0,
    cry = 0.0,
    crz = 0.0;
  var cubeTime = 0.0;
  var updates = [],
    updateTime = 0,
    fpsupdate = 0.0,
    fpsupdatemin = 0.0,
    fpsupdatemax = 0.0;
  const loop = (deltaTime) => {
    cubeTime += deltaTime * 90;
    updateTime += deltaTime;
    updates.push(deltaTime);
    if (updates.length > 60) {
      var n = updates.shift();
    };
    var l = updates.length,
      ftime = 0.0;
    var max = 0.0,
      min = 1000.0;
    updates.forEach((e) => {
      ftime += e;
      if (min > e) {
        min = e;
      };
      if (max < e) {
        max = e;
      };
      return;
    });
    fpsupdatemin = min;
    fpsupdatemax = max;
    fpsupdate = ftime / l;
    ctx.fillStyle = `#fff`;
    ctx.font = `12px serif`;
    var txt0 = ` 1 / deltaTime: [ FPS: ${(1 / deltaTime).toFixed(1)} ]`,
      txt1 = ` Average / deltaTime: [ FPS: ${(1 / fpsupdate).toFixed(1)} ]`,
      txt2 = ` Maximum  / deltaTime: [ FPS: ${(1 / fpsupdatemin).toFixed(1)} ]`,
      txt3 = ` Minimum / deltaTime: [ FPS: ${(1 / fpsupdatemax).toFixed(1)} ]`;
    var metrics0 = ctx.measureText(` FPS:`),
      metrics1 = ctx.measureText(txt0),
      metrics2 = ctx.measureText(txt1),
      metrics3 = ctx.measureText(txt2),
      metrics4 = ctx.measureText(txt3);
    var hmet0 = metrics0.actualBoundingBoxAscent + metrics0.actualBoundingBoxDescent + 2,
      hmet1 = metrics1.actualBoundingBoxAscent + metrics1.actualBoundingBoxDescent + 2,
      hmet2 = metrics2.actualBoundingBoxAscent + metrics2.actualBoundingBoxDescent + 2,
      hmet3 = metrics3.actualBoundingBoxAscent + metrics3.actualBoundingBoxDescent + 2,
      hmet4 = metrics4.actualBoundingBoxAscent + metrics4.actualBoundingBoxDescent + 2;
    ctx.fillText(` FPS:`, 0, hmet0);
    ctx.fillText(txt0, 0, hmet0 + hmet1);
    ctx.fillText(txt1, 0, hmet0 + hmet1 + hmet2);
    ctx.fillText(txt2, 0, hmet0 + hmet1 + hmet2 + hmet3);
    ctx.fillText(txt3, 0, hmet0 + hmet1 + hmet2 + hmet3 + hmet4);
    draw(cubeBuffs, 36, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, cubeTime * 0.3, cubeTime * 0.7, cubeTime);
    return;
  };
  var l,
    then = 0;
  l = (now) => {
    requestAnimationFrame(l);
    now *= 0.001;
    const dT = now - then;
    then = now;
    mat4.copy(projectionMatrix, aProjectionMatrix);
    mat4.copy(modelViewMatrix, aModelViewMatrix);
    mat4.translate(modelViewMatrix, modelViewMatrix, [
      cx, -cy,
      cz
    ]);
    mat4.rotate(projectionMatrix, projectionMatrix, (-crx) * DTR, [
      1,
      0,
      0
    ]);
    mat4.rotate(projectionMatrix, projectionMatrix, cry * DTR, [
      0,
      1,
      0
    ]);
    mat4.rotate(projectionMatrix, projectionMatrix, crz * DTR, [
      0,
      0,
      1
    ]);
    gl.clearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    gl.clearDepth(1.0);
    gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
    loop(dT);
    doDraw(gl, aVertexPosition, aVertexNormal, uProjectionMatrix, uModelViewMatrix, uNormalMatrix, uTransform, uRotationX, uRotationY, uRotationZ, projectionMatrix, modelViewMatrix);
    return;
  };
  const init = () => {
    cubeBuffs = getBuffers(gl, Object.Cube);
    cx = -6.0;
    cy = 6.0;
    cz = -6.0;
    crx = -45.0;
    cry = -45.0;
    return false;
  };
  const resize = () => {
    height = document.body.clientHeight;
    width = document.body.clientWidth;
    canvasctx.style.height = `${height}px`;
    canvasctx.style.width = `${width}px`;
    canvasctx.height = height;
    canvasctx.width = width;
    canvasgl.style.height = `${height}px`;
    canvasgl.style.width = `${width}px`;
    canvasgl.height = height;
    canvasgl.width = width;
    mat4.perspective(aProjectionMatrix, (45.0 * Math.PI) / 180.0, width / height, 0.0, 1000.0);
    gl.viewport(0, 0, width, height);
    return;
  };
  const ini = () => {
    gl.clearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    const shaders = initShaders(gl);
    vertexShader = shaders[`vertex`];
    fragmentShader = shaders[`fragment`];
    shaderProgram = gl.createProgram();
    gl.attachShader(shaderProgram, vertexShader);
    gl.attachShader(shaderProgram, fragmentShader);
    gl.linkProgram(shaderProgram);
    if (!gl.getProgramParameter(shaderProgram, gl.LINK_STATUS)) {
      alert(`Unable to initialize the shader program: ${gl.getProgramInfoLog(shaderProgram)}`);
      return true;
    };
    gl.useProgram(shaderProgram);
    aVertexPosition = gl.getAttribLocation(shaderProgram, `aVertexPosition`);
    aVertexNormal = gl.getAttribLocation(shaderProgram, `aVertexNormal`);
    uProjectionMatrix = gl.getUniformLocation(shaderProgram, `uProjectionMatrix`);
    uModelViewMatrix = gl.getUniformLocation(shaderProgram, `uModelViewMatrix`);
    uNormalMatrix = gl.getUniformLocation(shaderProgram, `uNormalMatrix`);
    uTransform = gl.getUniformLocation(shaderProgram, `uTransform`);
    uRotationX = gl.getUniformLocation(shaderProgram, `uRotationX`);
    uRotationY = gl.getUniformLocation(shaderProgram, `uRotationY`);
    uRotationZ = gl.getUniformLocation(shaderProgram, `uRotationZ`);
    gl.disable(gl.BLEND);
    gl.blendFunc(gl.SRC_ALPHA, gl.ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
    gl.enable(gl.CULL_FACE);
    gl.cullFace(gl.BACK);
    gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);
    gl.depthFunc(gl.LEQUAL);
    return init();
  };
  window.addEventListener(`load`, () => {
    canvasctx = document.createElement(`canvas`);
    canvasgl = document.createElement(`canvas`);
    canvasctx.style.imageRendering = `pixelated`;
    canvasctx.style.position = `fixed`;
    canvasctx.style.zIndex = `999`;
    canvasctx.style.left = `0px`;
    canvasctx.style.top = `0px`;
    canvasgl.style.position = `fixed`;
    canvasgl.style.zIndex = `989`;
    canvasgl.style.left = `0px`;
    canvasgl.style.top = `0px`;
    document.body.appendChild(canvasctx);
    document.body.appendChild(canvasgl);
    projectionMatrix = mat4.create();
    modelViewMatrix = mat4.create();
    aProjectionMatrix = mat4.create();
    aModelViewMatrix = mat4.create();
    ctx = canvasctx.getContext(`2d`);
    gl = canvasgl.getContext(`webgl2`, {
      'powerPreference': `high-performance`
    });
    if (ctx == null || typeof ctx == `undefined`) {
      console.error(`Unable to get 2D context`);
      alert(`Unable to get 2D context`);
      return;
    };
    if (gl == null || typeof gl == `undefined`) {
      console.error(`Unable to get WebGL2 context`);
      alert(`Unable to get WebGL2 context`);
      return;
    };
    resize();
    var cb;
    window.addEventListener(`resize`, () => {
      clearTimeout(cb);
      cb = setTimeout(resize, 150);
      return;
    });
    if (ini() == false) {
      then = performance.now() * 0.001;
      requestAnimationFrame(l);
    };
    return;
  });
  return;
})();
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://intre-webgl-rendering-engine.804kn.repl.co/gl-matrix-min.js"></script>
<!-- Modified version of gl-matrix as to not include imports -->
```

Comment: @Rabbid76
I explained this here:
`The reasoning for the cube being rotated within the vertex shader but the cosine and sine operations being performed outside of it is due to performance improvements.`

`Instead of changing a buffer for, say, 100 cubes and rotating each and every one of them, in order to rotate the cube, we just need to input one buffer. If you just want to rotate the model view projection, that's fine, but if you want to have two cubes (side by side) rotating in different directions or have a first-person shooter with different rotating objects, that's nearly impossible.`

Comment: No it is not an performance improvement. The improvement would be to compute a model matrix and pass that matrix to the shader. Anyway it is not sufficient to roatate `aVertexPosition` you also need to rotate the normal vector.

Comment: Why do you rotate the projection matrix (`crx`, `cry`, `crz`)? Instead you should rotate the view matrix. Note, also the rotation of view matrix needs to be applied to the normal vector. In the end the normal vector needs to be rotated with  `crx`, `cry`, `crz`, `uRotationX`, `uRotationY` and `uRotationZ`. The common way is to create a model view matrix with all the rotations (and trnaslations) and compute the normal vector form the model view matrix /inverse transpose upper left 3x3 of model view matrix).

Comment: @Rabbid76
I explained why the _**cosine**_ and _**sine**_ angles are calculated outside of the shader, and that's what I'm _**asking**_ in this post, attempting to rotate the normal vector just results in oddities (Rotating it the same way aVertexPosition), it results in random sides being blank and often it will get flipped. And I have everything computed, the model matrix is not rotated due to it messing with camera positioning and other factors, it's being calculated as a transformation for the camera.
perspective matrix: rotation
model matrix: translate

Comment: @Rabbid76 It was too long to fit here, but the modelviewmatrix is being transformed, not rotated. You could always just create another matrix and rotate it that way but it got similar results to rotating the cube matrix verticies.

Comment: You have to apply the same rotation to the normal vector as to the vertex coordinate. In your system this is not even possible, because some of the rotation is encoded in the projection matrix. Since the normal vector is a vector and not a point you must not apply the translation to the normal vector. Therefore the normal matrix is usually a 3x3 matrix. If you use a 4x4 matrix for the normal matrix the 4th component of the normal vector must be set 0.0. Even if you argue, the noram vector must still be transformed with `crx`, `cry`, `crz`, `uRotationX`, `uRotationY` and `uRotationZ`

Comment: @Rabbid76 I had tried that already, I don't know if my previous code was incorrect but I'll try it again

Comment: The most obvious mistake in your code is `highp vec4 transformedNormal = uNormalMatrix * vec4(aVertexNormal, 1.0);`. It has to be `highp vec4 transformedNormal = uNormalMatrix * vec4(aVertexNormal, 0.0);`. Note, `vec4(aVertexNormal, 0.0)` because it is a vector not a point. Anyway this will  not solve your problem, because the rotation is still missing.

Comment: @Rabbid76 https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGL_API/Tutorial/Lighting_in_WebGL

Comment: Yes, I see this is wrong. However it doesn't matter if the translation is (0, 0, 0)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250855/discussion-between-bomber87t-and-rabbid76).